# Bipartite graph "matching" with multiple edges per node

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I'll preface by saying that I know that the title is technically incorrect since a matching is defined such that each node has at most one edge. However I can't find the correct term so here I am

---

I have a matching problem that is modeled as a weighted bipartite graph with node sets $X$ and $Y$ where $|X|\neq|Y|$ and it can be assumed that each node in either set is connected to at least one node in the other set.

The goal is to find a (minimal) set of edges $E$ such that every node in the graph is the endpoint of at least one edge (i.e., $|E|=max(|X|, |Y|)$) while minimizing the sum of weights in $E$. Obviously this implies that some nodes will have more than one edge in $E$, in opposition to a minimum weight full matching where $|E|=min(|X|, |Y|)$ and some nodes may be left unmatched.

What would be the correct term to search instead of "matching" and is there an algorithm that can solve this problem?

Comment: You write that the condition taht "every node in the graph is the endpoint of at least one edge" is the same as |E|=max(|X|,|Y|), but those things are different. The set of all edges satisfies the first condition but not the second one in general.
)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I've edited to clarify the implicit assumption that we want the smallest possible amount of edges (or, if that's also different, |E|=min(|X|,|Y|) is the actual condition that makes sense for my application)

Comment: @Xilef11 If you want to minimize the number of edges first and the total weight only second, then you *should* use the strategy that begins with a maximum matching. The algorithm in my answer assumed that you want to minimize the total weight even if that means using more edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set of edges that includes every vertex as an endpoint is called an *edge cover*.

In the unweighted case, finding the minimum edge cover is no harder than finding a maximum matching. In fact, we begin by finding the maximum matching; then, for every vertex that is not covered by that maximum matching, just add an arbitrary edge to cover it.

---

In the weighted case, things are trickier, but there is *still* a way to reduce it to a bipartite matching problem.

1. Take our graph $G$ and create a copy $G'$.
2. Between every vertex $v \in V(G)$ and its copy $v' \in V(G')$, add an edge; let its weight be **twice** the minimum weight of any edge in $G$ that could cover $v$.
3. Find a minimum-weight perfect matching $M$ of the graph constructed in steps 1-2. (At least one perfect matching always exists: the matching that uses all the edges $vv'$ created in step 2.)
4. To find an edge cover of our original graph $G$, combine the following. First, include all edges in $M \cap E(G)$. Second, for every edge in $M$ of the form $vv'$, include the cheapest edge in $G$ covering $v$ (the one used to determine the cost of $vv'$) in the edge cover.

The idea is that *every* minimum edge cover has the following structure: a matching as a skeleton, plus additional edges which cover only one additional vertex each, and are the cheapest edge out of that vertex. And the big graph containing $G \cup G'$ is exactly what we need to make its perfect matchings mimic that structure.

By the way, if $G$ is bipartite with bipartition $(A,B)$, then the graph created in steps 1-2 is also bipartite with bipartition $(A \cup B', B \cup A')$. So we get a bipartite minimum-weight matching problem to solve, which is nice.

Comment: Is there a difference between this procedure and "start with a minimum weight full matching and, for each node not in the matching, add the cheapest edge connected to it"?

Comment: Yes; the size of the matching you start with will end up being the number of components in your edge cover, so starting with a min-weight full matching can produce suboptimal results if the best edge cover has fewer components. For example, suppose we have a complete bipartite graph with vertices $v_1, \dots, v_n$ on one side and $w_1, \dots, w_n$ on the other, and we weight it so that edges out of $v_1$ or $w_1$ have weight $1$ while all other edges have weight $10$. Then a min-weight perfect matching has weight $2 + 10(n-2)$, but there is an edge cover with weight $2(n-1)$.

Comment: "include the cheapest edge covering v in the edge cover" = "the cheapest edge *in G* that covers v"?

Comment: Yes - where else? (But I've edited to clarify.)

Comment: But how many matches are you going to allow in the bipartite case? Is it $\max(|A|,|B|)$, $|A|+|B|$, or something else? It seems to me that this number cannot be determined a priori.

Comment: @ZiruiWang The bipartite graph we construct has a perfect matching.

Comment: @MishaLavrov But the matching mapping $v$ to $v'$, and hence $A$ to $A'$ and $B'$ to $B$, is the only perfect matching! The only neighbor of $v'$ is $v$; if $v$ were mapped elsewhere, $v'$ would be left unmatched.

Comment: @ZiruiWang Unless $v$ is an isolated vertex in $G$, $v'$ has other neighbors in $G'$.